# Suppose $n$ divides $3^n + 4^n$. Show that $7$ divides $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $n \geq 2$ and $n$ is a divisor of $3^n + 4^n$. Prove that $7$ is a divisor of $n$.

**My work so far:**

I had a hypothesis that if $n| 3^n + 4^n$, then $n = 7^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. But this is not necessarily so. Take $n = 7⋅379$, where $3^7 + 4^7 = 7^2⋅379$. Then, $3^7+4^7$ divides $3^n + 4^n$, and since $n$ divides $3^7+4^7$, we must have $n|3^n+4^n$.

Comment: I find the exposition confusing: are you asking whether " if $\;n\;$ divides $\;3^n+4^n\;$ then $\;7\;$ divides $\;n\;$" ?

Comment: Experiencing difficulties with the translation.

 5 is a divisor or divides for 10?

Comment: You can say "$5$ divides $10$"  or "$5$ is a divisor of $10$".  they mean the same thing.

Comment: If $n$ is odd we have that $7$ divides $3^n+4^n$ since $4=-3$ mod($7$).  So, you'll see $7$ cropping up as a divisor a lot.  Do you have examples for $n>7$ in which $n$ divides $3^n+4^n$?

Comment: @lulu, a simple test with mathematica leads to $n=1, 7, 49, 343, 2401,2653,16807,18571,117649,129997\cdots$

Comment: @vrugtehagel  Thanks!

Comment: Your work is confusing. You take $n = 7 \cdot 379$, but never consider $3^n + 4^n$ at all, just $3^7 + 4^7$.

Comment: We can easily show that $n$ is odd. Then we can prove for every $d|n$ that $3^d+4^d | 3^n+4^n$. That should be useful

Comment: But this does not mean that $7|n$

Comment: I know that, but I feel like it should still be helpful for the solution. If I thought that solved the problem, I'd have posted it as answer.

Comment: I'm the case that $n$ is prime, it suffices to use Fermat's little theorem to show that $n$ cannot divide $3^n+4^n$ unless $n=7$.

Comment: You need to prove the statement $n \mid 3^n+4^n \implies 7 \mid n$. I would try to prove the equivalent statement $7 \nmid n \implies n \nmid 3^n+4^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\enspace n\mid 3^n+4^n$,  for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 2$.

Hence, $$3^n+4^n=nm, \quad for \enspace m\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Since $3^n+4^n$ is odd $\enspace (odd\cdot odd=odd, \enspace even\cdot even=even, \enspace  odd+even=odd)$, and since $\enspace n \mid 3^n+4^n$, we know that $n$ is also odd. Thus,  we can express $3^n+4^n$ as
$$3^n+4^n=(3+4)\bigg(3^{n-1}-3^{n-2}4+3^{n-3}4^2-\ldots +3^24^{n-3}-34^{n-2}+4^{n-1}\bigg)$$

$$3^n+4^n=7k \qquad$$ 
whereby $\enspace k=\big(3^{n-1}-3^{n-2}4+3^{n-3}4^2-\ldots +3^24^{n-3}-34^{n-2}+4^{n-1}\big).$

Since $\enspace 7 \mid 7k$, it follows that $\enspace 7 \mid 3^n+4^n$.

Thus, so far we have,
$$3^n+4^n=nm=7k$$

and hence, 
$$n=7\bigg(\frac{k}{m} \bigg)$$

If $\enspace m \mid k$, then great, we are done!

So, let's assume the contrary that $\enspace m \nmid k$. Since $\enspace m \nmid k$, there exists $q\in\mathbb{N}, q>0$ such that $m=7q$ and $n=\frac{k}{q}$, whereby $q\mid k$. $\enspace 7\nmid n$, since $\frac{n}{7}=\frac{k}{m}$. Hence, $gcd(n,7)=1$. We have already shown that $7\mid 7k$ and $n\mid 7k$. Thus,

$$gcd(n,7)=1, \enspace 7\mid 7k, \enspace n\mid 7k \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace 7n\mid 7k \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace n\mid k \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace \frac{k}{q}\mid k$$

Since $m\nmid k$, $k=mb+r$ for some $b,r\in \mathbb{Z}, \enspace 0\leq r < m$. For some $s\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$\frac{k}{q}\mid k \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace \frac{mb+r}{q}\mid k \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace \big(7b+\frac{r}{q}\big)\mid k \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace k=s\big(7b+\frac{r}{q}\big)$$

$$k=7sb+\frac{rs}{q}=mb+r \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace b(7s-m)=r\big(1-\frac{s}{q}\big) \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace \frac{7bq}{r}=\frac{q-s}{s-q} \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace \frac{7bq}{r}=-1 \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace 7bq=-r \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace r=-mb \enspace \Longrightarrow \enspace k=mb-mb=0$$

But we already know that $k>0$, hence a contradiction. Thus, our assumption is false, and $m\mid k$.

Hence, since $n=7\big(\frac{k}{m}\big)$ and $m \mid k$, therefore $7\mid n$.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've made a mistake in your proof. $m\nmid k$ does not imply $\gcd(m,k)=1$, take for example $6\nmid 20$ but $\gcd(6,20)\neq 1$

Comment: @vrugtehagel, thanks! I've edited my answer above.

Comment: Could you explain how $b(7s - m) = r(1 - \frac{s}{q})$ immediately implies $\frac{7bq}{r} = \frac{q - s}{s - q}$? That definitely isn't obvious, if at all true.

Comment: Because $m=7q$. Hence, $b(7s-7q)=r(1-\frac{s}{q}) \Longrightarrow 7bs-7bq=r\big(\frac{q-s}{q}\big) \Longrightarrow 7bq(s-q)=r(q-s) \Longrightarrow \frac{7bq}{r}=\frac{q-s}{s-q}$.

Comment: But dont we have $s = q$? Because $q(7b + \frac{r}{q}) = (mb + r) = k $. Do you cant divide by $s - q$.

Answer (score 5):

First, we note that $3 \nmid 3^n + 4^n$ and $4 \nmid 3^n + 4^n$. So $3 \nmid n$ and $2 \nmid n$.

Now, reworking $3^n + 4^n \equiv 0 \pmod n$. Since n is odd, we find 
\begin{equation}
3^n \equiv (-4)^n \pmod n.
\end{equation}
Since $\gcd(3, n) = 1$, we can take the inverse of $3 \mod n$, i. e. there exists $3^{-1}$ so that $3 \cdot 3^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$. Multiplying both sides by $(3^{-1})^n$ gives
\begin{equation}
(-4 \cdot 3^{-1})^n \equiv 1 \pmod n.
\end{equation}

Now, if $O_m(k)$ denotes the order of $k \mod m$, we know from algebra that
\begin{equation}
O(-4 \cdot 3^{-1}) \mid n.
\end{equation}

Now, to show that $7 \nmid n$ for any solution, let's assume $7 \nmid n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let's assume $n > 1$ is the smallest solution so that $7 \nmid n$ and $n \mid 3^n + 4^n$.
If we can show that either $n = 1$ or $7 \mid n$ or there exists an $m < n$ satisfying these properties, we're done.

Let's split 2 cases:

**(Case 1)**: $O_n(-4 \cdot 3^{-1}) = 1$ Then we're done, since that implies (using uniqueness of inverses):
\begin{equation}
(-4 \cdot 3^{-1}) \equiv 1 \pmod n \implies -4 \cdot 3^{-1} \equiv 3 \cdot 3^{-1} \pmod n  \\ \implies -4 \equiv 3 \pmod n \implies n \mid 7 \implies n = 1 \vee n = 7.
\end{equation}

**(Case 2)**: $O_n(-4 \cdot 3^{-1}) > 1$. Let $d = O_n(-4 \cdot 3^{-1})$.
Then $(-4 \cdot 3^{-1})^d \equiv 1 \pmod n$, and since $d \mid n$ we have $(-4 \cdot 3^{-1})^d \equiv 1 \pmod d$. $d$ is also odd, and
\begin{equation}
-4^d (3^{-1})^d \equiv 1 \pmod d \implies -4^d \equiv 3^d \pmod d
\end{equation}

If $O_d(-4 \cdot 3^{-1}) = 1$, then by the reasoning above $d \mid 7$. Since $d > 1$, we have $d = 7$. Since $d \mid n$, $7 \mid n$.

If $O_d(-4 \cdot 3^{-1}) > 1$, let m = $O_d(-4 \cdot 3^{-1})$. Then $m > 1$, $7 \nmid m$ and $m \mid 3^m + 4^m$. $m < n$, since $m \mid \varphi(n)$. So we found an $m < n$ satisfying the above conditions, implying $n$ is not the smallest.